# Error when including mongoose in Electron Vue app

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, mongoose, electron, vue-cli-5

I am trying to include mongoose in a Vue CLI app with electron-builder, but as soon as I require mongoose, I am receiving a bunch of loader errors. Does anyone else have this problem?

Steps to reproduce:

```
(vue-cli version 5.0.8 latest)

vue create my-project (v.3 / babel,sass,vuex,router / no history mode)

cd my-project

vue add electron-builder (v.13)

yarn add mongoose
```

In background.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
```

Node Version: 16.20.2

error  in ./node_modules/bson/lib/bson.mjs

Module parse failed: Cannot use keyword 'await' outside an async function (131:26)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

```
|     return nodeJsByteUtils.fromNumberArray(Array.from({ length: byteLength }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)));
| }
> const nodejsRandomBytes = await (async () => {
|     try {
|         return (await import('crypto')).randomBytes;

 @ ./node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/objectid.js 13:17-32
 @ ./node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js
 @ ./node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/mongoose/index.js
 @ ./src/background.js
 @ multi ./src/background.js
```

EDIT: I found that upgrading electron and putting mongoose in the electronBuilder.externals array it works now.

Comment: I would use a newer Node version, however it doesn't look like VueCLI supports after Node version 17

Comment: "I am receiving a bunch of loader errors" - which errors? The question is not constructive. 16 is new enough to not cause problems in general, updating node blindly creates problems, not solves them. 17 and other odd versions shouldn't ever be considered without a good reason because they are unstable. It's unclear how you determined and updated Node. Electron has Node  engine inside, you don't need a separate Node

Comment: The error log is too long to post on stack overflow, but I did show an example of one of the many errors which are all saying "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file."

Comment: They are all mongoose and mongodb errors too

Answer (score 0):

I found that upgrading electron to latest and putting mongoose in the electronBuilder.externals array in vue.config.js has it working now.